# adding a new module or functionality to inventory management system (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDd0O.png)

The above screenshot is from an Inventory management system.

As u see there are two ListViews in the above form (ListVIewTransaction, ListViewTransactionItems).

ListViewTransaction : Contains all the transactions.
ListViewTransactionItems : Contains all the items within a transaction.

My question is, is there any way to add a functionality to my system that supports return items or to undo a transaction. if yes, the following are the tables and queries.

```
Public Sub AddTransaction()
    Try
        sqL = "INSERT INTO [Transaction](InvoiceNo, TransactionDate, TransactionTime, Amount, VatAmount, TotalAmount, EmployeeID) VALUES('" & lblInvoice.Text & "', '" & Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "', '" & Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt") & "', '" & lblSubTotal.Text.Replace(",", "") & "', '" & lblVAT.Text.Replace(",", "") & "', '" & Val(lblTotalAmount.Text.Replace(",", "")) & "', '" & Val(frmMain.lblUser.Tag) & "')"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub



Public Sub AddTransactionDetails()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgw.Rows.Count - 1
        Try
            sqL = "INSERT INTO TransactionLineItem(InvoiceNo, ProductId, ItemPrice, Quantity, Discount, ExtendedPrice, TotalAmount) VALUES(@InvoiceNo, @ProductId, @ItemPrice, @Quantity, @Discount, @ExtendedPrice, @TotalAmount)"
            ConnDB()
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNo", lblInvoice.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", dgw.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemPrice", CDbl(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString.Replace(",", "")))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dgw.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", CDbl(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString.Replace(",", "")))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExtendedPrice", CDbl(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString.Replace(",", "")))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmount", CDbl(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString.Replace(",", "")))

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am afraid this question is too broad. I will say that I wouldn't delete or edit the existing transactions for returns or other credits. You want to leave a good audit trail. Perhaps negative transactions would work but I would rather have a separate series for credits.

Comment: @mary I agree with you, but what to do with the return items.

Comment: This too is subject to opinion. A return is not necessarily entered back into inventory. It could be scrapped, sent to rework, or even returned to your vendor. Because of the opinion factor and the lack of specific code problem, Stack Overflow is not the place for this question.

Comment: @mary just help me edit the transaction & create a new query to maintain the data quantities .... plz